# How to identify gnome-terminal profile?

Tags: c, bash, gnome-terminal

I posted a question on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230367/how-to-get-gnome-terminal-profile-for-current-window-or-profileid) a while back. As there is no action, and I have also dug some more, I'll try here. Possibly a more correct place, (and I don't know if it is possible to [move questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14159/how-do-i-find-the-window-dimensions-and-position-accurately) any more (I do not get any of those options)).

Anyhow:

Is there a way to get gnome-terminal profile ID? Need it in bash script – to do e.g. –

```
gconftool-2 "do some change to some value for current profile."
```

In my endeavour for an answer to this I have made some progress – but no satisfying solution. To be honest it truly scares me how shielded the application is from doing modifications from command line **being a terminal emulator**! To me it is incomprehensible.

Besides touching the source of gnome-terminal, (I do not wan a custom version), is there some *legit* way to get this? By the fact it is a wrapper for vte, it uses various shared libraries, some way I haven’t thought of, etc.

Add some C code into the mix is OK.

So far:

- I have checked out the "save-config" option, but as it is 1. not satisfactory, aka 100%, and 2. more important this **also** is [going to be removed](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-terminal/commit/?id=7391805f5cc259a0e04e07710b2a6db9452bd8e9) it fails completely. See my own answer below for more detail.
- There is no environment variable for this.
- dbus: Doesn't seem to be any messages transmitted or any functions available for this kind of information. Have tested both current (3.6.0) version and latest develop.
- injection: tho it is probable, and have played around with injecting custom code to it, it is such an error-prone endeavour it is not a solution.

Comment: Have you tried using `dconf list '/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/'`. Referencing [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1206763)

Answer (score 2):

### If anyone wonder etc.

Decided to have another look at this - and made a little progress.

Using the built-in option `--save-config` there is these properties of interest:

```
Role=gnome-terminal-window-2587-1856448950-1359348087
ActiveTerminal=Terminal0xa896200
Geometry=110x87+900+1
WorkingDirectory=/home/xxx/tmp
```

Looking at it closer. Opened two windows in short succession and did a `save-config`.

### Role

We can split it to the various parts:

```
gnome-terminal-window
2587
1856448950
1359348087
```

#### PID

`2587` is same for both, and after a quick `pstree 2587 -p` we find it to be the PID. Further an `echo $$` locates our bash (or which ever one prefer).

#### Time of start

Now the second number is wildly different giving a clue it is probably a random value. The last one, tho, is with only the last digit in diff. Most probably a time-stamp. I know I'm in `tmp` directory for *this* window - so, by using our knowledge of the [proc file system](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html):

```
# btime: boot time, in seconds since the Epoch
$ cat /proc/stat | grep ^btime | cut -d' ' -f2
1359039155
# starttime: The time in jiffies the process started after system boot.
$ cat /proc/$$/stat | cut -d' ' -f22
30893222

# WANT: 1359348087
btime + starttime / Hertz
1359039155 + (30893222 / 100) = 1359348087.22 ~ 1359348087
```

OK. Last digit is time-stamp on start by Epoch. But unfortunately it is not by jiffies and a rounded value so if we have started several windows by e.g. a script we can end up with same value.

*(After some checking it also seems like seconds is rounded by **round to nearest** not towards zero etc.)*

#### Random value

OK. So what about the value after PID? Most probably a random value, but to be sure. To check this we have to go to the source.

```
$ git clone git://git.gnome.org/gnome-terminal
$ gnome-terminal --version
GNOME Terminal 3.6.0

$ git log --grep="3\.6\.0"
commit f4d291a90dc4f513fc15f80fdebcdc3c3349b70a
...    
    Version 3.6.0

$ git checkout f4d291a90dc4f513fc15f80fdebcdc3c3349b70a
```

After some digging we find:

```
# terminal-util.c
48: void
terminal_util_set_unique_role (GtkWindow *window, const char *prefix)
{
    char *role;

    role = g_strdup_printf(
        "%s-%d-%d-%d", 
        prefix, 
        getpid(), 
        g_random_int(), 
        (int) time (NULL)
    );
    gtk_window_set_role (window, role);
    g_free (role);
}
```

OK. Not only do we confirm that the second is a random value, but also that PI and time is correct.

#### Geometry

```
xwininfo -id $(xdotool getactivewindow) | \
grep '^\s*-geometry' | \
sed 's/^\s*[^ ]* \(.*\)/\1/'

# yields 110x87+900+1
```

OK. Now we have three values to check against:

- Time
- Geometry
- Path

---

Problem is that even with this we can easily have two windows with those values at same value. And more important; some genius has decided to remove this from the options of the application.

---

#### Terminal Window hex

Looking further at the code one find that the hex value in `ActiveTerminal` etc. is a pointer value to current address in memory of a struct holding current window. AKA not very usefull if one doesn't want to hack memory mappings.